# Cakephp Install on Bluehost

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

How do I set up Cakephp to work properly on Bluehost? Should I place my app, cake and vendor folders as well as .htaccess and index.php files in the /public_html/ directory? I followed the instructions here... http://book.cakephp.org/view/37/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess to no avail. All I see when I type the name to my website is a blank page!

Comment: The your app log files for clues, a blank page can mean almost anything in cake (/app/tmp/logs/*). I have my site hosted on BlueHost, on a subdomain though, and cake worked just fine with no special configuration. If you don't know what the errors mean, bring 'em in!

Comment: Is there a way you can show me how you did that dr. Hannibal Lecter? So if I understand correctly, you didn't use .htaccess?

Comment: I did, and they worked fine. I simply uploaded everything, set the permissions on the /app/tmp folder and that was pretty much it (of course, setting up database connection also). However, it might be possible that some files were not uploaded correctly and that cake can't recover. This is why checking your logs would be a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that I followed to set up everything can be found at this site... http://www.ad7six.com/MiBlog/ProductionSetup

- /cake_install
- /cake_install/app
- /cake_install/cake
- /cake_install/vendor
- /public_html/.htaccess
- /public_html/index.php

/public_html will have other information originally found in app/webroot but that's explained in the link above

```
    if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    //define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
    define('ROOT',DS.'cake_install');
}

    if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    //define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
    define('APP_DIR',DS.'app');
}

    if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    //define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT);
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH',DS.'cake_install');
}
```

Comment: above link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

With bluehost, dont forget that the folders outside the webroot (ie your home folder) are also accessible for your application - no particular need to put the framework inside folders that are open to the outside world.